# how to make a line renderer use colliders?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to figure out how I can add a collider to a line renderer because in my game I am trying to make it so that when the enemy collides with the line, the enemy disappears but I don't know how to add colliders to the line. please let me know if I am missing something! Thanks so much! (all in 2d)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [LineRenderer.BakeMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.BakeMesh.html).

Use it like this:

```
public yourLineRendererComponent;
public MeshCollider meshCollider; //attached to the lineRenderer gameobject or child
private Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

void setLrCollider() {
    LineRenderer lineRenderer = yourLineRendererComponent;
    lineRenderer.startWidth = 1; //optional
    lineRenderer.endWidth = 1; //optional

    /*****optional to set the points with code*****/
    // canbe done in the inspector but points needs to be set for bakemesh towork 
    Vector3 lineRendererPathVector3Array = new Vector3[];
    lineRendererPathVector3Array [0] = new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);            
    lineRendererPathVector3Array [1] = new Vector3(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f);
    lineRendererPathVector3Array [2] = new Vector3(0.2f,0.3f,0.4f);
    lineRendererPathVector3Array [3] = new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f);
    lineRenderer.positionCount = lineRendererPathVector3Array.Length;
    lineRenderer.SetPositions(lineRendererPathVector3Array);
    /*****optional to set the points with code finish*****/

    //below lines create a mesh collider with the line renderer's shape
    lineRenderer.BakeMesh(mesh, Camera.main);
    meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;
}
```

Comment: the line is constantly changing, will this always change the collider? thanks so much

Comment: if you call `setLrCollider` it will. You will need to arrange your `Vector3[]` array for every update

Comment: I tried this but that script is for 3d and mine is 2d. i also got a lot of errors. suggestions? thanks.